# awk or sed to Parse Elements from Directory Path

Tags: command-line, awk, sed

Say I have several directories of varying length in the form

```
/tmp/(1) I. First Majuscule Roman Numeral/01. First Arabic Numeral/a. First Grapheme
/tmp/(2) II. Second Majuscule/03. Third Arabic/d. Fourth
```

that I want to parse so the output is

```
I.01.a.
II.03.d.
```

What's the awk and/or sed solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are tho *only* directories beneath `/tmp`:

```
$ find /tmp -mindepth 3 -type d -print | sed -e 's/\.[^/]*/./g' -e 's/^.* //' -e 's#/##g'
I.01.a.
II.03.d.
```

The `find` command finds the directories on level 3 and prints out their full path.  The result of this step is

```
/tmp/(1) I. First Majuscule Roman Numeral/01. First Arabic Numeral/a. First Grapheme
/tmp/(2) II. Second Majuscule/03. Third Arabic/d. Fourth
```

The `sed` command does three things:

1. replaces everything from a dot up until the next slash with a dot, creating

   ```
   /tmp/(1) I./01./a.
   /tmp/(2) II./03./d.
   ```
2. removes the bit up until the first space,

   ```
   I./01./a.
   II./03./d.
   ```
3. removes the slashes,

   ```
   I.01.a.
   II.03.d.
   ```

Answer (score 2):

No need for awk or sed, really; bash globbing and regular-expression testing can do it:

```
for d in /tmp/*/*/*
do
  if [[ $d =~ ^/tmp/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]*).*/([^[:space:]]*).*/([^[:space:]]*) ]]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
I.01.a.
II.03.d.
```

The regular expression inside breaks down to three components:

1. `^/tmp/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]*).*/`

The filename must start `^` with `/tmp/` then must have some non-space characters followed by a space followed by (capturing this) non-space characters, then anything up to a forward-slash

1. `([^[:space:]]*).*/`

... followed by (capturing this) non-space characters, then anything up to a forward-slash

1. `([^[:space:]]*)`

... followed by (capturing this) non-space characters) -- followed by ... nothing we care about.

Bash saves those captured bits into the BASH_REMATCH array, based on the order of the capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

For the hell of it, since there isn't an `awk` reply yet...

```
awk -v FS="" '
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i==" " || $i=="/") {
            part=""
        } else if ($i==".") {
            printf "%s.", part
        } else {
            part=part FS $i
        }
    }
}
END { printf "\n" }'
```

Sets field separator to "" so it can loop through each character. Looks for " " or "/" in the current character and resets the holder (part variable) if it finds one. If it finds "." print out the holder, otherwise concatenate the current character onto the holder. Appends linefeed when it's done.

Output on example:

```
I.01.a.
II.03.d.
```